# Headless chrome disconnections during jasmine tests

Tags: gitlab-ci, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

I have an angular 15 project and I run my tests with jasmine and karma:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
```

I have default karma config to run tests locally with Chrome and it works well.

I needed another configuration to run tests on my CI/CD pipeline and there's the beginning of my issues:

```
browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000
      }
    },
```

My pipeline runs on docker containers with public gitlab runners:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: node:18-alpine
  dependencies:
    - install_dependencies
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
    expire_in: 1 hour
  script:
    - apk add chromium
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
    - node_modules/.bin/ng test --code-coverage --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --watch=false
```

Sometimes, but not always, I have the following error:

```
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 461 of 694 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1 min 0.636 secs)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 462 of 694 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1 min 0.642 secs)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 463 of 694 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1 min 1.067 secs)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 464 of 694 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1 min 1.068 secs)
02 03 2023 18:05:23.730:WARN [Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64)]: Disconnected (0 times) reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (ping timeout)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (ping timeout)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 464 of 694 DISCONNECTED (2 mins 26.054 secs / 1 min 1.068 secs)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (ping timeout)
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Linux x86_64): Executed 464 of 694 DISCONNECTED (2 mins 26.054 secs / 1 min 1.068 secs)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:04
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The error never occurs locally and the only solution I presently have is retrying the job. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the arg `--disable-dev-shm-usage` has fixed my problem.

In your case it would be something like:

```
browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000
  }
}
```